# Axis is locked when sculpting?

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting

I am currently sculpting and for some reason I can't add detail to the side of my mesh; it only works for the front and back.

- If I grab my nose, its axis is locked to X and Z. It can't move on the Y axis but can be moved on the X and Z axes.
- I can only sculpt on the front and back of the mesh, I can't sculpt on the right or left.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you don't have any axes locked in *Tool shelf > Symmetry / Lock > Lock*:

[image]

Comment: i dont even have this option.

Comment: nvm i found it, it was somewhere else on the bar. thankyou :)

Comment: @user3536490 What version of blender are you using? You might want to update if you aren't using the latest version (currently 2.70, but 2.71 is to be released in a few days)..