# sculpt grab tool problem

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, vertices, sculpting

the sculpt grab tool is pulling the mesh's vertices in one axis it wont let me pull in free mode it only gets me to pull in one axis

as how i move the mouse cursor and then doesn't let me move it in free mode 
is there any thing i can do to fix the problem?

*it is a very annoying problem because am working on a character's expressions and its hard to do it without sculpt because it has many vertices*

Comment: What do you mean by "sculpt pull tool"? Anyway if you are sculpting and sculpted geometry is moving only on one axis make sure there aren't any axes locked from moving in the settings of the sculpting brush, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12193/axis-is-locked-when-sculpting

Comment: oh uh excuse me i meant the grab tool and the symmetry/lock is all clean it has no problems its all unlocked and yet its pulling the vertices in the direction i move the mouse cursor  to and then moves it only to it and never makes me move it in a free movement

Comment: Look at the settings there for the brush to see if it is locked to a particular plane like View or X, Y, Z. This is just below the regular pressure controls.